# Mysql Update on slow internet

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Recently i faced new problem using on MySql.Data.MySqlClient
my code is here

```
Public Function executeDMLSQL(ByVal sSql As String, ByRef sResult As String) As Integer
    Dim sReturn As String = ""
    Dim irows As Integer = 0
    conn_A = New MySqlConnection
    Try
        conn_A.ConnectionString = connString
        conn_A.Open()
        Dim sComm As New MySqlCommand
        sComm.CommandText = sSql
        sComm.Connection = conn_A
        irows = sComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn_A.Close()
        sResult = SUCCESS
    Catch ex As Exception
        sResult = SERROR & ": " & ex.Message
        If (conn_A.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
            conn_A.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    conn_A = Nothing
    Return irows
End Function
```

this executeDMLSQL Function working well on good internet connection. But when internet connection become slow this Function  Return me True but with out update or insert data to mysql database.

My question is is it my fault or is it bug...

Thanks.

Comment: Well if it fails but your code consider it a success, obviously there's a bug somewhere. That said, there is very few link with the speed of your internet connection : we're not talking about a lot of data to transfer anyway !

Comment: after your query check the value of sComm.RecordsAffected . If it is 0, then nothing changed so don't return True.